# Android Cardview Click To Different Activity

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

I am having a hard time figuring this one out. I am creating an Android app where the user (once logged in) sees an activity with a cardview list inside a recycler view.

I want the user to be able to click on a card and go to a different activity. If you click on card 1 you must go to the activity for game 1. If you click on card 2 you must go to the activity for game 2. Etc...

This is my "main" activity once logged in:

```
package com.afmob.gaming;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GamesCatalog extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    // Added for cardview
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AlbumsAdapter adapter;
    private List<Album> albumList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.games_catalog);

        // Might have to change the toolbar to the system one, also in the xml file

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Added for cardview
        initCollapsingToolbar();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        albumList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new AlbumsAdapter(this, albumList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        prepareAlbums();

        try {
            Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.cover).into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Added for cardview
    /**
     * Initializing collapsing toolbar
     * Will show and hide the toolbar title on scroll
     */
    private void initCollapsingToolbar() {
        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

        // hiding & showing the title when toolbar expanded & collapsed
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow = false;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Adding few albums for testing
     */
    private void prepareAlbums() {
        int[] covers = new int[]{
                R.drawable.album1,
                R.drawable.album2,
                R.drawable.album3,
                R.drawable.album4,
                R.drawable.album5,
                R.drawable.album6,
                R.drawable.album7,
                R.drawable.album8,
                R.drawable.album9,
                R.drawable.album10,
                R.drawable.album11};

        Album a = new Album("Maroon5", 13, covers[0]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Sugar Ray", 8, covers[1]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Bon Jovi", 11, covers[2]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("The Corrs", 12, covers[3]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("The Cranberries", 14, covers[4]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Westlife", 1, covers[5]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Black Eyed Peas", 11, covers[6]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("VivaLaVida", 14, covers[7]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("The Cardigans", 11, covers[8]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Pussycat Dolls", 17, covers[9]);
        albumList.add(a);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
     */
    public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        private int spanCount;
        private int spacing;
        private boolean includeEdge;

        public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
            this.spanCount = spanCount;
            this.spacing = spacing;
            this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
            int column = position % spanCount; // item column

            if (includeEdge) {
                outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

                if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                    outRect.top = spacing;
                }
                outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
            } else {
                outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
                if (position >= spanCount) {
                    outRect.top = spacing; // item top
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Converting dp to pixel
     */
    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id==R.id.navigate) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my adapter:

```
package com.afmob.gaming;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Ravi Tamada on 18/05/16.
 */
public class AlbumsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Album> albumList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
        }
    }


    public AlbumsAdapter(Context mContext, List<Album> albumList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.albumList = albumList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.album_card, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Album album = albumList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(album.getName());
        holder.count.setText(album.getNumOfSongs() + " songs");

        // loading album cover using Glide library
        Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

        holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing popup menu when tapping on 3 dots
     */
    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        // inflate menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_album, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        popup.show();
    }

    /**
     * Click listener for popup menu items
     */
    class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

        public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_add_favourite:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Add to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_play_next:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Play next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Added in for click on each card


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return albumList.size();
    }
}
```

this is how the individual card looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/album_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/album_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/overflow"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_height"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_margin_top"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dots" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is what the recyclerview looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/viewBg"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.afmob.gaming.GamesCatalog"
    tools:showIn="@layout/games_catalog">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the main view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/love_music"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/backdrop_title"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/backdrop_subtitle"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_subtitle" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Please Help Me!

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: hey buddy, i want to have each card click to its own activity, card1 goes to activity1, card2 goes to activity2, etc...

Comment: okay but what problem are you facing? Any errors?

Comment: Try this link to make click effect of recyclerview http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/  and in that write code startActivity().. to go next activity as per position click.

Comment: @Kaushal28 i dont know how to implement the code that makes these clicks happen. I will read this now, thanks

Comment: You should reduce the code to the bare minimum which is needed, to show the problem. While reducing the (copy of your) code, your chances are high to solve the problem yourself. This is far too much code for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit MyViewHolder as:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;
        public View itemView;
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            itemView = view;
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
        }
    }
```

onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Album album = albumList.get(position);
        final int pos = position;
        holder.title.setText(album.getName());
        holder.count.setText(album.getNumOfSongs() + " songs");

        // loading album cover using Glide library
        Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

        holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
            }
        });
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(pos == 0){              
                   view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),Activity1.class));
               }else if(pos == 1){
                   view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),Activity2.class));
              }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks very much @cancit ive added this now, was missing a ; after itemView = view is that correct? also it says Cannot resolve symbol 'v' for the v.getContext any solution for that?

Comment: @JoostHesselberth it was supposed to be view, I edited my answer

Comment: awesome it works like a charm!  much much appreciated, can you maybe give me your email or skype, always good to keep on file in case i need some work done.

Answer (score 0):

1.create an interface

```
public interface ItemClickListener  {

    void onClick(View view, int position);

}
```

2. Then in your adapter :

   ```
   ItemClickListener itemClickListener ;




     public void setClickListener (ItemClickListener itemClickListener){
          this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener ;

   }
   ```

   Inside MyViewHolder class

   ```
     public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
    View.OnClickListener{
       public TextView title, count;
      public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

      public MyViewHolder(View view) {
       super(view);
       title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
       count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
       thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
       overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
       view.setOnCLickListener(this);
       }
       @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       if (itemClickListener != null) itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());

   }
   }
   ```

3.In your activity :

```
implements ItemClickListener
```

and then you can Override OnClick() method in your activity

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
  // here you can get the position of the cardview and you can use switch 
 // case to go to desired activity by using startACtivity()
}
```

Hope this will help you .